# HTML - a row of buttons overlaying an image

Tags: html, css

I have a 256x64 image that I would like to overlay a row of 4 buttons on.
jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c5a03w4r/

```
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border-style: solid;
      }
      .sidebar {
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 100%;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      .container {
        width: 256px;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .buttons {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="container">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ynrCcsx.png">
        <div class="buttons">
          <button>1</button>
          <button>2</button>
          <button>3</button>
          <button>4</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My current problem is I cant find a way to put the buttons over the image or vice versa, doesnt really matter as long as when you click the button onclick event happens. If theres an even better completely different way of doing this, I don't mind as long as it works. The buttons need to be in a row right next to each other, one corresponding to each slot in the image. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```css
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-style: solid;
  }

  .sidebar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  .container {
    position: relative;
    width: 256px;
    display: flex
  }
  
  .buttons {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 242px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 7px;
    top: 7px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="container">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ynrCcsx.png">
        <div class="buttons">
          <button>1</button>
          <button>2</button>
          <button>3</button>
          <button>4</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

---

Feel free to adjust the `.buttons` class to have the exact overlay effect that you are looking for.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f1r45dtn/1/)

Comment: I've changed the top and left to 0px and made the sizes 256 and 64, and works exactly like needed, thank you

Comment: Gald to hear. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd rather just use relative positioning on the buttons.